# Is it possible to install WSL2 in a standalone partition?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Let's say I have a PC with a 1T disk, can I create two partitions in the disk, 800G for Windows 11, and 200G for a partition dedicated for Linux. Then, install Windows 11 in the 800G partition, and then in Windows install WSL2 directly on the 200G partition?

I'm asking the question because I really want my WSL2 to be ask fast as possible.

Comment: Why downvote? Because it’s “dumb”? Please don’t.

Answer (score 0):

> is it technically possible to directly install WSL2 on a physical drive instead of VDHX?

No, you can easily realize that with `wsl --help`. Neither `--install` nor `--import` allows you to choose not to use a VHDX. (In other words, a distro registration always binds to a VHDX.)

But you can (bare) mount a *dedicated* drive. While you can't use it for a distro installation, you can use it for your "data" (e.g. valuable big projects and/or their compilation sites).

Note: I don't know exactly what happen when you mount only a partition of a partitioned drive "from the outside" with `wsl.exe`, but *IIRC* the whole drive will need to be taken offline from the Windows side anyway so that it can be attached / SCSI-passthrough'd to the Linux (WSL) kernel. So if e.g. you are using a laptop which can have at most one internal drive, it would be a no go. (You should be able to attach a USB *fixed* drive though, where fixed means it declares a SCSI Removable Medium Bit of `0`, which should be the case for most UAS-bridged SATA/NVMe SSDs.)

Comment: Thanks @Tom Yan, I think I can buy another NVMe solely for /home, because I believe that's where most IO occurs in my WSL2. That way hopefully my valuable big projects (all in /home) will build much faster.

Comment: Since you can mount a physical drive, you can chroot to give you that drive as root inside that chroot environment